# Get all comment lines

Tags: regex, matlab

How to get (or remove) all comment lines from a matlab file?

Lines may start with no or an arbitrary number of whitespaces followed by one or more `%`, followed by the comment.

Using

```
only_comments = regexp(raw_string, '(?m)^[ ]*[%].*?$', 'match');
```

fails. Also, how to make sure tabs will be catched?

As I understand this its

- `(?m)` line mode
- `^` beginning of line
- `[ ]*` none or any number of white spaces
- `[%].*?$` followed by a `%` and then any charachter until the line end is reached.

Whats wrong?

Comment: could you post a sample comment line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
only_comments = regexp(raw_string, '(?m)^[ ]*[%]+.*?$', 'match');
```

OR

```
only_comments = regexp(raw_string, '(?m)^ *%+.*$', 'match');
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `<space>*` Matches zero or more spaces.
- `%+` Matches one or more `%`
- `.*` Matches any character but not of line breaks.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: Whats the difference between `[ ]*` and ` *` (note the whitespace in the second fragment)?

Comment: no difference. You don't need to add empty space into a character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?m)^[ ]*%+.*$
```

Think you need this.your regex `(?m)^[ ]*[%].*?$` does not quantify `%`.It will match only 1 `%`.You need to use `%+` to match one or more of it.

Comment: To clearify: actually after `%` comes the comment and the entire line should match (or stripped).